# AngularJS Module separation & combine module in a page

Tags: angularjs

I am developing angularjs project. I want to separate code as modularize. After seperating module wise, i want to combine that in a page. How i combine modules in a single page?

Comment: You can use Grunt.js

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you've included the source of each module in your index.html:

```
<script src="/bower_components/module-1/dist/module-1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/module-2/dist/module-2.min.js"></script>
```

Then in your index.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'module1Name',
  'module2Name'
]);
```

Comment: Thank u richard. is there any good modular separation blog or pdf available? please send link if available.

Comment: No worries. Try this one: https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/03/27/13-step-guide-angularjs-modularization/